# How to set the value of a grand total property in a viewmodel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

How can I set the TotalSum to be a grand total of all the LineSums in my List?

This is a shopping cart, and I need to calculate the sum for each item in the list (product price * quantity), and the grand total of the shopping cart (lineSum1+lineSum2+lineSum3, etc...)

```
public class ViewModelShoppingCart
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public List<ViewModelShoppingCartItem> ShoppingCartItems { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalSum
    {
        set
        {
            // This clearly isn't working:
            TotalSum = ShoppingCartItems.Sum();
        }
    }
}

public class ViewModelShoppingCartItem
{
    public string ProductTitle { get; set; }
    public decimal ProductPrice { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal LineSum
    {
        set
        {
            LineSum = ProductPrice * Quantity;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [overload of `Sum`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb549046(v=vs.110).aspx) that takes the selector:

```
public decimal TotalSum => ShoppingCartItems.Sum(item => item.LineSum);
```

You also have to fix the `ViewModelShoppingCartItem.LineSum`-property:

```
public class ViewModelShoppingCartItem
{
    // ...
    public decimal ProductPrice { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal LineSum => ProductPrice * Quantity;
}
```

Comment: This will cause a StackOverflow no? Should be a `get` with a `return`?

Comment: @DavidG: look again ;)

Comment: Ah yes, I guess we were on the same track :)